# How do I play back a video encoded with x264 in QuickTime?

Tags: macos, mac, codec, quicktime, video-codecs

I recently encoded a screencast using x264.  The video is here:

http://www.libsys.und.edu/dev/ssl.avi

It works fine in VLC, but QuickTime claims it needs extra components to play it.  I'm confused.  I thought x264 was a clone of H.264, which QT has native support for?

Anyway, a friend of mine is having trouble getting it to play back on Mac OS X (10.6.8), and I see the same problem in my Windows 7 box.  Either I did it wrong or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add codecs to Quicktime (which thus gets inherited by iLife and other things that embed Quicktime for video playback).

[Perian](http://perian.org/) is a really easy to install bundle of codecs for quicktime. If you don't have it installed, I STRONGLY urge you to go install it now.

If it doesn't play back with that, you can always just encourage your friend to [install VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html), though I've found with Perian, I'm usually covered very well.

If it still doesn't play, try encoding that video differently, as between VLC and Perian, the playback coverage is pretty extensive.

Comment: For Windows: [K-Lite Codecs](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm)

Comment: @Will you bet. Perian rocks, who ever made it deserves a massive hug from a person they find to be extra-ordinarily attractive.